# source command in fish shell

Tags: linux, fish

the  command works nicely in fish terminal :

```
source ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

and this is a related fish function in the config.fish

```
function sf
  command source ~/.config/fish/config.fish
end
```

when I run it I get this error :

```
Command 'source' not found, did you mean:

  command 'gource' from deb gource (0.51-1build1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 59): 
  command source ~/.config/fish/config.fish
          ^
in function 'sf'
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please try with 
`function sf
  command . ~/.config/fish/config.fish
end
`
and see if it works. You just need to replace `source` with `.`

Comment: @gautamits it returns this error : 


    ~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 59): The file “.” is not executable by this user
      command . ~/.config/fish/config.fish
          ^
    in function 'sf'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`source` is not an *external command* - there is no /usr/bin/source to execute. There can't be, as `source` needs to be able to alter the environment of *the current shell*, so it *has to be* a builtin.

Simply leave off the `command`.